# Beyond Compare - Remove unecessary content (BETWEEN ")

Tags: beyondcompare

I'm comparing two files and I need to ignore everything that is in between ".
Like, File1 "ASD" and File2 "ABCDOOP" = Ignore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define an importance rule to mark everything between `"` as unimportant:

In the example the between `"` is only an unimportant difference.

[image]

The rule works also with multiple unimportant texts in one line:

[image]

You can define the rule in Session -> Session Settings. Then the Tab `Importance`. Then you can add the rule with `+`. The _text to *"`, the *regular expression*-checkbox must be marked.